# Opencv Image segmentation for licence plate

Tags: java, opencv, ocr, image-segmentation

I working on a project that will read licence plates, my plan is

1. Converting the image to grayscale for better performance
2. Use Histogram equalizer to bring out the licence plate characters
3. Blur the image to remove some noise
4. Use adaptive threshold to binaries the image
5. Use open and close morphology
6. Detect the rectangular bounding box for the licence plate

Well, the issue is: my code is not so good, the result is so bad I cannot detect the rectangle, below is my code:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 0);
    Imgproc.blur(image, image, new Size(3, 3));
    Imgproc.equalizeHist(image, image);
    Mat openElem = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(1, 1));
    Mat closeElem = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(1, 1));
    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(image, image, 225, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2);
```

The input image:

[image: input image]

The output image:

[image: Output image]

If anyone with experience would help I will appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is what I came up with

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 0);
    originalFrameGrayScale = image.clone();

    Mat morph = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(9, 3));
    Imgproc.morphologyEx(image, image, Imgproc.MORPH_TOPHAT, morph);
    Imgproc.Sobel(image, image, -1, 2, 0);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(image, image, new Size(5,5), 3,3);
    Imgproc.morphologyEx(image, image, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, morph);
    Imgproc.threshold(image, image, 200, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
    Vector<Rect> rectangles = detectionContour(image);
```

And find the greatest contour with height, width and area matching certain values
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFmNU.png)

Answer (score 2):

In the first is better to detect the plate position in the image, just follow steps below:

1. Convert to gray

   cvCvtColor(image, grayScale, CV_BGR2GRAY);

[image]

2. Do sobel

   Mat sobel = new Mat(grayScale.size(), CvType.CV_16S);
   cvSobel(grayScale, sobel, 2, 0, 7);
   Mat temp = new Mat(sobel.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
   convertScaleAbs(sobel, temp, 0.00390625, 0);

[image]

3. Do threshold

   cvThreshold(sobel, threshold, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY| CV_THRESH_OTSU);[image]
4. Do morphology

   Mat kernal = cvCreateStructuringElementEx(3,1, 1, 0, CV_SHAPE_RECT);
   cvDilate(threshold, erode_dilate, kernal, 2);//X
   vErode(erode_dilate, erode_dilate, kernal, 4);//X
   cvDilate(erode_dilate, erode_dilate, kernal, 2);//X

   kernal = cvCreateStructuringElementEx(1, 3, 0, 1, CV_SHAPE_RECT);
   cvErode(erode_dilate, erode_dilate, kernal, 1);// Y
   cvDilate(erode_dilate, erode_dilate, kernal, 2);

[image]

5. Now you are able to detect the rectangle in the image:

[image]

6. Then you can process the plate for OCR

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Please explain `5. Now you are able to detect the rectangle in the image:`

Comment: @ZdaR because of your down vote, so there is nothing to be explained. Please read first when to down vote or up vote.

Comment: I am sorry if I failed to explain my point, but I would be curious to know that from step 4, where you have approx. 50 contours, how have you filtered out the only license plate contour, if that would have been explained and supported with some code snippet then it would be much beneficial for other people seeking assistance for the same problem :)

Comment: Hmm, if you ask me like this, you are welcome! Because that part if you know the contours it will be easily filtered out, just check the height and width and the possible size of the each contours, e.g: width must be greater than the height and the size must be greater and smaller than some value (according to the situation). In such way you can filter out the invalid rectangle.

Comment: The point here is to make the plate to be like a rectangle in the binary image

Comment: But that would not be the case always, the input images can be randomly taken there is a high chance of false positive, In your approach you are dependent upon the `sobel` operator which is used to detect edges and there can be many rectangle shaped objects in the input image, there must be some way of filtering only rects with white background and black markings.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I told before that how you filter out the invalid rectangles is up to you, there is a lot of ways to do, I just made a simple example, with checking height and width you can filter out lot of invalid rectangles, then you can continue filter this time with background as you mentioned, and so on.

Comment: And also at the end you can use the OCR way to filter, I mean you can OCR the rectangle and check if some character was detected if not, it not a valid rectangle, But must remember that the expensive filter we must do at the end, for example, first we use the height and width to filter, it is very cheap process for computer and then background and so on...